# Unxpected token : for JSON string in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a json file which is generated by Java component and I trying to parse that json file via Javascript. But if I use this code:

```
var foo = JSON.parse('js/test.json');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Strange is I am generating this JSON via `JSONObject` which of-course produces valid JSON string. I tried with few online validators, and all of them are showing as a valid json. But javascript is throwing me this error.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this error? I searched many questions on SO but no luck. I posted my json [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3959)

Comment: Is 'js/test.json' a URL? Because that doesn't look like a valid JSON expression to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, it's a JSON file under `js` folder in web app.

Comment: `JSON.parse` takes a string of JSON, not a filename/url.

Comment: @Xymostech, then how do I read that from file? Can you please guide me?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Xymostech no, pure JS.

Comment: create xmlhttprequest and grab json content by reading file and then do parsing

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` parses JSON string expressions into javascript objects. I suggest you make an [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to `js/test.json` and then I think your parse will work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.onload = getJSON;
httpRequest.open('get', 'js/test.json', true);
httpRequest.responseType = "json";
httpRequest.send();


function getJSON(){var foo=httpRequest.response;}
```